# why some android elf file has interpreter path?

Tags: linux, android, elf, reverse-engineering

I am learning the elf file format for Android, but I have found that some elf files can specify the loader through the interpreter path in the program header. However, the elf test file I wrote myself through Android Studio does not have this attribute. What is the reason for this?

In elf files with an interpreter path, I can specify my own loader linker to get an earlier elf debugging time, but now many files do not have an interpreter path. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: *However, the elf test file I wrote myself through Android Studio does not have this attribute* How did you specify that it was supposed to have a `PT_INTERP` field?

Comment: I just wrote a so file by default (such as the default jni project in Android Studio), so what I want to ask is why some so files have segments with specified linkers, and whether there is a method to add this property.

Comment: An example is Linker and Linker64 in Android, where Linker has an interpreter path but Linker64 does not. These two files are located in/system/bin